# Is there a way to import a txt or rft file from a dxl script?

Tags: file, text, import, ibm-doors

I am trying to import a text file to my dxl script to use the words included in the txt as strings for a comparation. Is there a way to do so?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, of course. You can read the context of a file using a Stream variable, like in

```
Syntax:
Stream read [binary] (string filename)
bool end (Stream strm)

// Read from a stream. var can be of type: Buffer, char, real, int, string
<Stream>  >>  var [ >> var [ >> ...]]

// Special Read Functions: 
<Stream>  >=  <Buffer var       // Read one text line including whitespace
<Stream>  ->  <Buffer var>  // Read one text line. Omit leading whitespace
string readFile (string filename)   // Returns the contents of a file a string

Example:
string filename = "c:/datafile.txt"
Stream input = read filename

real cost
for (input >> cost; !end input; input >> cost) {
    print cost "\n"
}

close input
```

In your case, you would read the stream into a variable of type Buffer. Depending on your needs, you would also have to split a line into several words, e.g. seperated by space. If you do not need to split the values, you could also read the stream directly into a string variable.

Reading an RTF file is much more complicated as far as I know. I think you will have to know about the internal structure of RTF files and be able to distinguish formatting information from real string or use a COM library. Perhaps it is possible to use one of the richText features of DOORS, look at the help or at Google, I am not so fluent in DOORS w/ RTF.